# Как в jQuery cделать append а не замену load?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Как в jQuery cделать `append` а не замену `load`?
`load` полностью меняет `div`, а как сделать, чтоб он добавлялся в конец `div` не удаляя предыдущие элементы?

Answer (score 4):

Если Вам нужно подгрузить контент в блок, не заменяя его предыдущего содержимого, а дописывая его, нужно посылать запрос методом `.get(...)`, примерно так:

```
$.get('page.html',function(data){
    $('div').append(data);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$('div').append('somedata');
```